# Using DirectoryQ difference with windows and Unix naming, forward slash problem

Tags: files-and-directories

update: send email to Wolfram support. CASE 3561304. Will update if they confirm this is a bug or not.

---

Should Mathematica  `DirectoryQ["z/"]` return False when the folder `z` actually exist just because one used `/` in the folder name?  But then, why does `DirectoryQ["z\\"]` return true?

`DirectoryQ["z"]` return `True`. It is only when adding a forward slash that it returns `False`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

On Linux, `/` is part of folder name:

```
>mkdir z
>if test -d z/; then echo "exist"; fi
    exist
```

It also works without `/`.

Therefore I think `DirectoryQ["z/"]` should return `True` and not `False`.

I am on windows 7. But Mathematica supports unix naming of folders on windows also. Just like windows itself does. But this only affects the above command.

Here is the DOS command on the same PC above, and you can see that windows accept `/` on folder name:

```
X:\>dir
 Volume in drive X is New Volume
 Directory of X:\

03/21/2016  05:48 PM    <DIR>          data
03/21/2016  05:43 PM             1,012 t.nb
03/21/2016  05:44 PM    <DIR>          z

X:\>IF EXIST z/ (echo YES) ELSE (echo NO)
YES

X:\>IF EXIST z\ (echo YES) ELSE (echo NO)
YES

X:\>IF EXIST z (echo YES) ELSE (echo NO)
YES

X:\>IF EXIST z0 (echo YES) ELSE (echo NO)
NO
```

**Question is:**    Why Mathematica `DirectoryQ["z/"]` return `False` when folder exist?

Windows 7, Mathematica 10.4, 64 bit.,

Comment: Seems to be a bug: `SetDirectory` supports directory paths ending with `"/"` while `DirectoryQ` produces wrong answer without warning (tested with versions 10.4 and 8.0.4 on Win7 x64). It is worth to report it to the tech support.

Comment: A workaround could be to filter the file name : `FileNameJoin@FileNameSplit["z/", OperatingSystem -> "Windows"]` returns `z` for me on OSX.